# Correct use of static

Tags: java, mongodb, static

Currently I am using mongodb with java. I don't want to reopen my connection to the datastore every time, so I thought I should make a static variable:

```
package Config;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.google.code.morphia.*;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

public class Config {

    static String dbUrl = "url";
    static int dbPort = portnumber;
    static String username = "user";
    static String password = "pw";
    static String dbName = "dbname";
    public static Datastore ds;

    public static Datastore getDatastore() throws UnknownHostException,
            MongoException {
        if (ds == null) {
            ds = connect();
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public static Datastore connect() throws UnknownHostException,
            MongoException {
        Mongo m = new Mongo(dbUrl, dbPort);
        Datastore ds = new Morphia().createDatastore(m, dbName);
        boolean con = ds.getDB().authenticate(username, password.toCharArray());// todo
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I would use it like this:

```
Config.getDatastore().doSomthing();
```

Beside those un-handled exceptions, is this the correct way of using a `static` variable?

Comment: Googling around tells me the MongoDB Java driver pools connections internally: http://www.littlelostmanuals.com/2011/11/increasing-mongodb-connection-pool.html You can "reopen" them without losing performance.

Comment: Also, if this is a webapp, then `getDataStore()` is glaringly non-thread-safe. You're not guaranteed that every request will get the same `DataSource` instance, the first few that hit the race condition can get several different ones.

Comment: Use a singleton pattern : [Check here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given `Config` seems to indicate that this class should be a singleton, and if so, then using `static` variables for all members is fine. Will you have multiple `Configs`, or only one?

If `Config` isn't intended to be a singleton, then `static` isn't required in this case, or if so, only if it's ok to share your `Datastore` with *every* instance of your `Config` class. You'll achieve your goals with a simple - *non*-static - member variable, and you can still have, e.g. a `getDataStore` method. But each `Config` class will have it's *own* `Datastore`

Only use `static` if you want to also *share* that `Datastore` among multiple instances of your `Config` class.

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to share the config class to all my classes. They all should have the same datastore. I want to prevent multiple object creations like ´new Mongo´ and ´new Morphia´. I will have a look at singleton

Answer (score 4):

Better would be making `Config` class as a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

> is this the correct way of using a static variable?

well, your code seems to compile so as per the language its correct. As far as semantics are concerned the usage *depends*. it depends on the class in questions, the design you want to achieve.

I would personally go for a [connection pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/). If several connections are not required, i may go for a `singleton` if i need to maintain only one connection. If a single connection is not required i would go with a member variable.

In your case, it would depend on how you want to use the `config` class. In general design terms, what you have done is `problematic` for following reasons:

- Everything is static in your class, it serves no purpose in terms of object oriented-ness.
- You can not unit test this class unless you use `powermock` or some other framework.
- what happens when someone calls `connect()` several times?

***Note:** `Singleton` is an [`anti-pattern`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons). Generally any global state is bad. I would avoid it as much as i can.